# Parsley + Unable to validate Email address For Full Width Character

Tags: jquery, html, regex, submit, parsley

Trying to write on Email Validation Check for Full Width Character Parsley :-

JS Code:-

```
window.Parsley.addValidator('validateFullWidthCharacters', {
  validateString: function(_value) {
    regex = /[\u3000-\u303F]|[\u3040-\u309F]|[\u30A0-\u30FF]|[\uFF00-\uFFEF]|[\u4E00-\u9FAF]|[\u2605-\u2606]|[\u2190-\u2195]|\u203B/;
    if (regex.test(_value)) {
      return false;
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  },
  messages: {
    en: 'Please enter a valid email address.'
  }
});
```

Works fine and validate the email by giving error message

> ｒａｈｕｌ@ｍａｉｌ.ｃｏｍ

but if I changed the email to below one, does not work

> rahul@ｍａｉｌ.ｃｏｍ

```
<input placeholder="e.g. mail@example.com" class="form-control parsley-success" id="user_email" data-parsley-required="" data-parsley-type="email" data-parsley-validate-full-width-characters="true" type="email" value="" name="user[email]" data-parsley-id="17">
```

Please give suggestion to resolve this.

Comment: Your question should be marked with regex tag IMO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex just match fullwidth characters, you have to test your value with normal characters.

There is a bug or maybe an "expected behavior" with input type="email", that it converts fullwidth characters into normal ones if it is valid until @.

A solution for you is to change type="email" to type="text" and use another pattern for email and edit that if of you to return regex.test instead

```
regex = /^([a-z0-9_\.-]+\@[\da-z\.-]+\.[a-z\.]{2,6})$/gm
```

The new test

```
regex = /^([a-z0-9_\.-]+\@[\da-z\.-]+\.[a-z\.]{2,6})$/gm
/^([a-z0-9_\.-]+\@[\da-z\.-]+\.[a-z\.]{2,6})$/gm
regex.test('rahul@ｍａｉｌ.ｃｏｍ')
false
regex.test('ｒａｈｕｌ@mail.com')
false
regex.test('rahul@mail.com')
true
```

your code would become:

```
window.Parsley.addValidator('validateFullWidthCharacters', {
  validateString: function(_value) {
    regex = /^([a-z0-9_\.-]+\@[\da-z\.-]+\.[a-z\.]{2,6})$/gm;
    return regex.test(_value);
  },
  messages: {
    en: 'Please enter a valid email address.'
  }
});
```

html

```
<input placeholder="e.g. mail@example.com" class="form-control parsley-success" id="user_email" data-parsley-required="" data-parsley-type="email" data-parsley-validate-full-width-characters="true" type="text" value="" name="user[email]" data-parsley-id="17">
```

```js
    window.Parsley
        .addValidator('validateFullWidthCharacters', {
            requirementType: 'string',
            validateString: function (value, requirement) {
                regex = /^([a-z0-9_\.-]+\@[\da-z\.-]+\.[a-z\.]{2,6})$/gm;
                return regex.test(value);
            },
            messages: {
                en: 'Please enter a valid email address.'
            }
        });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/parsley.js/2.7.2/parsley.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<form data-parsley-validate>
    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="e.g. address@example.ext" data-parsley-validate-full-width-characters="true">
    <button>Submit</button>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Rubyist do you want to accept or reject 'rahul@ｍａｉｌ.ｃｏｍ' ? with that new regex it will accept emails with only normal characters

Comment: I want to reject this email because of full-width character in the email address.

Comment: my code is doing that, I copied console result for you, it is giving false

Comment: Ya @ramon-marques, Thanks. Let me check.

Comment: Sorry Still no success, I dnt know what is happening with response.

Comment: Then your problem is not that piece of code only, you will have to provide more source code

Comment: Question updated with input box. and already copied the js function as it is.

Comment: @Rubyist I created another snippet and got same problem you are getting. But i notice that for some reason the form submission or input type email or something, is transforming that '@ｍａｉｌ.ｃｏｍ' into '@mail.com'. Then you are good with that code...

Comment: look at this http://storage3.static.itmages.com/i/17/0613/h_1497363290_2424308_b21858df14.png

Comment: @Rubyist I edited my answer, just change your type="email" to type="text" and do that validation

Comment: @Rubyist I notice you came here to accept your question edition, but did you notice I found a solution for you? Accept answer if it solves your problem, please.

Comment: @RamonMarques solution indeed works. Should be the accepted response :)

Answer (score 1):

Before running the validation on the email string try to remove all the extra spaces from the string.

Like this

`tr = str.replace(/\s+/g, '');`

Comment: Please visit https://fullwidthtext.blogspot.in/ and type any email address.

Comment: His example have no whitespace hehe

Answer (score -1):

regex to validate email is:

```
/^((([a-zA-Z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-zA-Z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-zA-Z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-zA-Z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-zA-Z]|\d|-|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-zA-Z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-zA-Z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-zA-Z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-zA-Z]|\d|-|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-zA-Z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))$/
```